# Creating pull requests automatically using jgit

Tags: github, pull-request, jgit

I want to build an automation to create many pull requests on GIT by just click of a button. Input for the API would be source and destination branch. I have come across ways to checkout repository using jgit but did not get anything to create pull request automatically. Please assist.

Comment: If there are any ways through CLI which can be configured using jgit then that would also hep.

Comment: JGit does not fit your use-case. You should use REST API to do this. Take a look at [GitHub REST API v3 • Create a pull request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request)